# How to change only the middle TabBarItem background color?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I want to change the background color of a middle TabBarItem. In this image home is selected and middle tab is not selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this...

```
// Add background color to middle tabBarItem
let itemIndex = 2
let bgColor = UIColor(red: 0.08, green: 0.726, blue: 0.702, alpha: 1.0)

let itemWidth = tabBar.frame.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let bgView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(itemWidth * itemIndex, 0, itemWidth, tabBar.frame.height))
bgView.backgroundColor = bgColor
tabBar.insertSubview(bgView, atIndex: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,

```
     NSArray *arr = self.tabBarController.tabBar.subviews;
NSLog(@"tabbar subview : %@",arr);

UIButton *button = (UIButton*)[arr objectAtIndex:3];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

In your first viewcontroller of your tabbarcontroller.